# Fetch all records from table A where id = somvalue in B plus records which don't have id in B

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables a `coupons` table and a `coupon_city_map` table.

| id | coupon_code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | OFFER20 |
| 2 | OFFER10 |
| 3 | OFFER50 |
| 4 | OFFER40 |
| 5 | OFFER90 |

| coupon_Id | city_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 |

I need coupons with ids `1 4, and 5` for `city_id = 2`.

So It should fetch all the coupons where `city_id=2` i.e. coupons with id `1 and 4`

and it should also fetch coupons which don't have key in `coupon_city_map` i.e `5`.

*This is what I have tried but the query in `[Op.or]` is not working, and it returns all the coupons instead.*

```
let coupons = await Coupon.findAll({
      where: {
        [Op.or]: [
          { '$CouponCities.city_id$': city_id },
          { '$CouponCities.coupon_id$': null },
        ],
        ...filters // other filter like is_active: true
      },
      include: {
        model: CouponCity,
        attributes: [],
      },
      attributes: ['id', 'coupon_code', 'discount_per', 'flat_discount', 'discount_upto', 'description', 'display'],
    });
```

The query being generated

```
SELECT `Coupon`.`id`, 
       `Coupon`.`coupon_code`, 
       `Coupon`.`discount_per`, 
       `Coupon`.`flat_discount`, 
       `Coupon`.`discount_upto`, 
       `Coupon`.`description`, 
       `Coupon`.`display` 
FROM `coupons` AS `Coupon` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `coupon_city_map` AS `CouponCities` ON `Coupon`.`id` = `CouponCities`.`coupon_id` 
WHERE (`Coupon`.`user_id` IS NULL OR `Coupon`.`user_id` = 1) 
  AND `Coupon`.`is_active` = true 
  AND `Coupon`.`is_external` = false 
  AND `Coupon`.`start_date` < '2020-12-30 10:33:20' 
  AND `Coupon`.`expiry_date` > '2020-12-30 10:33:20';
```

***Update***
I also tried below, but still it is returning all the coupons.

```
let coupons = await Coupon.findAll({
    // where: {
    //   ...filters,
    // },
    include: {
      model: CouponCity,
      required: false,
      where: {
        [Op.or]: [
          {
            zone_id: zoneId,
          }, {
            coupon_id: null,
          },
        ],
      },
      attributes: [],
    },
    attributes: ['id', 'coupon_code', 'discount_per', 'flat_discount','discount_upto', 'description', 'display'],
 });
```

...and it generates below query.

```
SELECT `Coupon`.`id`, 
       `Coupon`.`coupon_code`, 
       `Coupon`.`discount_per`, 
       `Coupon`.`flat_discount`, 
       `Coupon`.`discount_upto`, 
       `Coupon`.`description`, 
       `Coupon`.`display` 
FROM   `coupons` AS `Coupon` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `coupon_city_map` AS `CouponCities` 
                    ON `Coupon`.`id` = `CouponCities`.`coupon_id` 
                       AND ( `CouponCities`.`zone_id` = 1 
                             AND `CouponCities`.`coupon_id` IS NULL ) 
WHERE  `Coupon`.`is_active` = true 
       AND `Coupon`.`is_external` = false;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me, query is mess but it works. I am posting all the codes for better understanding for anyone interested.

Here `zone` is city.

```
{
  const filters = {
    start_date: {
      [Op.lt]: new Date(),
    },
    expiry_date: {
      [Op.gt]: new Date(),
    },
  };
  if (userId) {
    filters[Op.or] = [{
      user_id: null,
    }, {
      user_id: userId,
    }];
    filters[Op.and] = {
      [Op.or]: [
        sequelize.literal('CouponZones.zone_id = 1'),
        sequelize.literal('CouponZones.coupon_id IS  null')
      ],
    };
  } else {
    filters.user_id = null;
  }
  let coupons = await Coupon.findAll({
    where: {
      ...filters,
    },
    include: {
      model: CouponZone,
      attributes: [],
    },
    attributes: ['id', 'coupon_code', 'discount_per', 'flat_discount', 'discount_upto', 'description', 'display'],
  });
```

This is the query it generates.

```
SELECT `Coupon`.`id`, 
       `Coupon`.`coupon_code`, 
       `Coupon`.`discount_per`, 
       `Coupon`.`flat_discount`, 
       `Coupon`.`discount_upto`, 
       `Coupon`.`description`, 
       `Coupon`.`display` 
FROM   `coupons` AS `Coupon` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `coupon_zone_map` AS `CouponZones` 
                    ON `Coupon`.`id` = `CouponZones`.`coupon_id` 
WHERE  ( `Coupon`.`user_id` IS NULL 
          OR `Coupon`.`user_id` = 1 ) 
       AND ((CouponZones.zone_id = 1 OR CouponZones.coupon_id IS  null)) 
       AND `Coupon`.`is_active` = true 
       AND `Coupon`.`is_external` = false;
```

Comment: There is rarely much point in left joining tables from which you select no columns

Comment: @Strawberry I don't need any columns from that table, just need to filter according to them. Maybe I should try using `through` and many to many association?

Comment: That would normally be an INNER JOIN

Answer (score -1):

*Use UNION*

You can write query like below

```
SELECT coupons.* 
FROM   coupons, 
       coupon_city_map 
WHERE  coupons.id = coupon_city_map.coupon_id 
       AND coupon_city_map.city_id = 2 
UNION 
SELECT coupons.* 
FROM   coupons 
WHERE  coupons.id NOT IN(SELECT coupon_city_map.coupon_id 
                         FROM   coupon_city_map)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think sequelize supports `unions`

Comment: Note that we stopped writing queries this way circa 1992. Why not JOIN us?